# Pyinstaller: QWebEngineView doesn't play nicely with other modules

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller, qwebengineview

I have an app that uses both QWebEngineView and Matplotlib. Specifically, just importing Matplotlib is enough to break the QWebEngineView in the generated executable. Here is a table of what works/doesn't work on my Windows 10 machine. I cannot reproduce this on Linux. Regrettably, the deployed EXE file has to be on Windows.

**Edit**: It's not just Matplotlib. QWebEngineView also misbehaves with [pyqtgraph](https://www.pyqtgraph.org/) and [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

|  | QWebEngineView | Matplotlib | test.html renders OK? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| run from python | X |  | YES |
| run from python | X | X | YES |
| run from EXE | X |  | YES |
| run from EXE | X | X | NO |

Here's what a "normal" rendering of test.html. It has a formatted title, a table, and an SVG image:

[image]

Here's a bad rendering of the same file:

[image]

Something in Matplotlib screws up QWebEngine rendering. Is there some sort of workaround for this behavior?

The code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

# ~ import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # <------ this is the line that breaks it


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    view = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(view)
    
    lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    webview =  QWebEngineView()
    
    layout.addWidget(lineedit)
    layout.addWidget(webview)
    
    lineedit.setText('file:///test.html')
    
    def handleReturn():
        qurl = QUrl(lineedit.text())
        webview.setUrl(qurl)
    
    lineedit.returnPressed.connect(handleReturn)
    handleReturn()
    
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Pyinstaller spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
# this file gives build options for pyinstaller

added_files = [ ('qt.conf',   '.'),
                ('test.html', '.'),
                ('test.svg',  '.') ]

a = Analysis(['webengine.py'],
             datas= added_files)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='webengine',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               name='webengine')
```

test.html

```
<html><body>
<p><h1>Test HTML Document</h1></p>
<table style="width:80%" border="1">
<tr><th>C1</th><th>C2</th><th>C3</th><th>C4</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>6</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
<tr><td>the</td><td>quick</td><td>brown</td><td>fox</td></tr>
<tr><td>jumped</td><td>over</td><td>the lazy</td><td>dog</td></tr>
</table>
<p><img src="test.svg" width="50%"></p>
</body></html>
```

[test.svg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="svg2" width="620" height="472" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs id="defs4">
  <path id="box1" d="m0 0h77v210h-77z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"/>
  <path id="box2" d="m0 0h77v60h-77z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"/>
 </defs>
 <path id="bg" d="m0 0h620v472h-620z" fill="#fff"/>
 <g id="g9" transform="translate(2 1)">
  <use id="use11" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box1"/>
  <use id="use13" x="77" fill="#ff0" xlink:href="#box1"/>
  <use id="use15" x="154" fill="#0ff" xlink:href="#box1"/>
  <use id="use17" x="231" fill="#0f0" xlink:href="#box1"/>
  <use id="use19" x="308" fill="#f0f" xlink:href="#box1"/>
  <use id="use21" x="385" fill="red" xlink:href="#box1"/>
  <use id="use23" x="462" fill="#00f" xlink:href="#box1"/>
  <use id="use25" x="539" xlink:href="#box1"/>
 </g>
 <g id="g45" transform="translate(2 220)">
  <use id="use47" fill="#0f0" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use49" x="77" fill="#0f0" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use51" x="154" fill="#0f0" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use53" x="231" fill="#0f0" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use55" x="308" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use57" x="385" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use59" x="462" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use61" x="539" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <text id="green100" x="30" y="35" fill="#fff" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">0.59</text>
 </g>
 <g id="g27" transform="translate(2 280)">
  <use id="use29" fill="red" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use31" x="77" fill="red" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use33" x="154" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use35" x="231" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use37" x="308" fill="red" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use39" x="385" fill="red" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use41" x="462" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use43" x="539" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <text id="red100" x="20" y="35" fill="#fff" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">+0.30</text>
 </g>
 <g id="g63" transform="translate(2 340)">
  <use id="use65" fill="#00f" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use67" x="77" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use69" x="154" fill="#00f" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use71" x="231" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use73" x="308" fill="#00f" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use75" x="385" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use77" x="462" fill="#00f" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="use79" x="539" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <text id="blue100" x="20" y="35" fill="#fff" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">+0.11</text>
 </g>
 <g id="g63" transform="translate(2 410)">
  <use id="grey100" fill="#fff" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="grey89" x="77" fill="#e3e3e3" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="grey70" x="154" fill="#b2b2b2" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="grey59" x="231" fill="#969696" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="grey41" x="308" fill="#696969" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="grey30" x="385" fill="#4d4d4d" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="grey11" x="462" fill="#1c1c1c" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <use id="grey0" x="539" fill="#000" xlink:href="#box2"/>
  <text id="txgrey100" x="20" y="35" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">100%</text>
  <text id="txgrey89" x="102" y="35" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">89%</text>
  <text id="txgrey70" x="179" y="35" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">70%</text>
  <text id="txgrey59" x="256" y="35" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">59%</text>
  <text id="txgrey41" x="333" y="35" fill="#fff" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">41%</text>
  <text id="txgrey30" x="408" y="35" fill="#fff" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">30%</text>
  <text id="txgrey11" x="487" y="35" fill="#fff" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">11%</text>
  <text id="txgrey0" x="569" y="35" fill="#fff" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="1" xml:space="preserve">0%</text>
 </g>
 <text id="text3446-0" x="90" y="184" fill="#fff" font-size="180" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="4" xml:space="preserve">TEST</text>
 <text id="text3446" x="80" y="174" font-family="DejaVu Sans, Arial, Helvetica" stroke-width="4" xml:space="preserve"><tspan id="tspan3448" x="80" y="174" font-size="180">TEST</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "compiled" on another Windows machine and the QWebEngineView rendered nicely. So then I had to figure out the difference between the "bad" and the "good" machine.

To list installed python modules and their versions, you can use

```
pip list
```

I don't know if this gathers modules you install outside of pip (e.g. install via .msi in Windows or `apt install python3-<python module>` in Debian Linux

I'm not really sure which one was the offending package. I didn't have the patience to go one by one -- too time consuming. But here is a list that works:

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| altgraph | 0.17 |
| cycler | 0.10.0 |
| future | 0.18.2 |
| importlib-metadata | 3.4.0 |
| kiwisolver | 1.3.1 |
| matplotlib | 3.4.2 |
| numpy | 1.21.1 |
| pandas | 1.2.1 |
| pdfkit | 0.6.1 |
| pefile | 2021.5.24 |
| Pillow | 8.1.2 |
| pip | 21.0.1 |
| pycparser | 2.20 |
| pyinstaller | 4.5.1 |
| pyinstaller-hooks-contrib | 2021.2 |
| pyparsing | 2.4.7 |
| PyQt5 | 5.15.4 |
| PyQt5-Qt5 | 5.15.2 |
| PyQt5-sip | 12.8.1 |
| pyqtgraph | 0.11.1 |
| PyQtWebEngine | 5.15.4 |
| PyQtWebEngine-Qt5 | 5.15.2 |
| pyserial | 3.5 |
| python-dateutil | 2.8.1 |
| pythonnet | 2.5.2 |
| pytz | 2021.1 |
| pyusb | 1.1.1 |
| PyVISA | 1.11.3 |
| pywin32 | 301 |
| pywin32-ctypes | 0.2.0 |
| scipy | 1.6.1 |
| setuptools | 47.1.0 |
| six | 1.15.0 |
| typing-extensions | 3.7.4.3 |
| zipp | 3.4.0 |